# Regex to capture end of line value

Tags: regex, perl, notepad++

i have a source code that i need to capture. the whole file is of one line but i am not able to capture the data that i require.

```
allow=ok&secret=432643286754
```

now i need to capture this data 432643286754 which changes everytime.

i tried using Left and Right selectors by using "secret=" on left but since the source ends at the end of the value, i dont have any thing to put in right selector.

so i need to know how can i capture this data? is there any regex cmd that can let me.?

thanks

Comment: Please show the code you tried. See [perldoc perlretut](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html) for more information on Perl regexes

Comment: like i said, i dont tried the to use secret= on left side and left the right side blank and there was nothing in source.

other than that, nothing. i dint know the regex to use or any way of using CSS selector as this is the whole code i shared here

Comment: Try this `/secret=(\d+)$/`

Comment: dint work.. the code is of 40 letters if that helps, numberic plus lower alphabets mixed

Comment: If it is not only numbers, then `\d+` will not work yes. Lower case characters can be for example `[a-z]`

Comment: End of line is indicated by a `$`, see [perlretut](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html)

Comment: so what will be the new cmd if you replace \d+ with a-z?
its a code of 40letters containing 0-9 and a-z

Comment: Then it will be something like `/secret=([a-z\d]+)$/`. You can test it from the command line like this: `perl -E '$_="secret=01abz4"; /secret=([a-z\d]+)$/ and say $1'`. If it is exactly 40 characters you can use `[a-z\d]{40}` to be more specific

Comment: Please ask a new question if the regex is not related to Perl. It is important to keep ideas and questions separate, see [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2):

Is this URI parsing? It *looks* like URI parsing.

```
use URI qw();
use URI::QueryParam qw();
my $u = URI->new;
$u->query('allow=ok&secret=432643286754');
print $u->query_param('secret'); # 432643286754
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to capture all digits à the end of the string, no matter what's before those digits, you can use `(\d+)$`

Check the [result here](https://regex101.com/r/vjZCUR/1).

Answer (score 0):

Please be clear with your question and example. Be more specific with what are the possible values of secret=<..>

Check if anything below works for you

```
#This will capture anything between = and EOL
my ($data) = /secret=(.*)$/;

#This will capture alphanumeric characters + underscore
my ($data) = /secret=(\w)$/;

#This will capture alphanumeric characters
my ($data) = /secret=([a-zA-Z0-9])$/;
```